# JavaScript how do i make a loop that asks the user for input and loops until they type exit

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

JavaScript how do i make a loop that asks the user for input and loops until they type exit
and then the program will display the minimum value that they entered

```
var Student = prompt("Enter Student Name: ");
var StudentArr = new Array(Student);

var mark = parseInt( prompt("Enter Student Mark: ") );
var markArr = new Array();


function min (mark){
    var min = Number.Max_Value;
    for(var i = 0; i < mark.length; i++){
       if(number(mark[i]) < min)
           min = number(mark[i]); 
    }
    return mark;
}
var smallest = min(mark);

        document.write(smallest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var input = prompt("test");
var min = parseInt(input);

while (input !== "exit") {
    input = parseInt(input);
    if (input < min) {
        min = input;
    }
    input = prompt("test");
}
alert(min);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Jtxu/

But this is the minimal functioning code. You might want to add some `if` to verifiy if the input is a valid number.